# How to change lib-path for an RStudio project?

Tags: rstudio

I set `R_LIBS_USER` to my desired library path in my system environment variables (I already moved my old library to that location). RStudio respects that path when I start the program without opening an existing file. But when I open RStudio by clicking on an `.Rproj` file, it loads an old lib path and ignores `R_LIBS_USER` (`.libPaths()` returns the old path). I searched my `%UserProfile%` directory and project directory for mentions of the old string. I can't find anything in `%UserProfile%` directory except in the `history_database` file, and likewise in the project directory, except for one mention in `.Rproj-user\B37F6204\pcs\packages-pane.pper`:

```
{
    "installOptions" : {
        "installDependencies" : true,
        "installFromRepository" : true,
        "libraryPath" : "<my-userprofile-path>/R/win-library/3.3"
    }
}
```

This looked promising, but when I changed it, RStudio still ignores it when I open the project.

Clicking on .Rproj files is pretty convenient so I'd like to fix this.

RStudio version is `1.0.136`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3
```

Comment: Does it help if you set this in your `~/.Renviron` file (or similarly located startup R file)? [see `?Startup` for more information]

Comment: Yes, I tried `.Renviron` in my `%USERPROFILE%` directory as well. Still gets overriden by loading the `.Rproj` file.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this on my Windows VM (the library path set by `R_LIBS_USER` was respected even when opening a dummy project using the `.Rproj` file). Can you append the output of `Sys.getenv()` after launching from the `.Rproj` file just to see if the `R_LIBS_USER` environment variable is still set?

Comment: I posted my Sys.getenvs() from with and without opening an .Rproj here: https://www.diffchecker.com/3lZnPrXE (left side is without opening an Rproj, i.e. it respects my `R_LIBS_USER`). But I'm pretty convinced it's some kind of project persistence. When I create a new test project from the correct case (where it's respecting my current path), close it, change my R_LIBS_USER to a different path, then open the test project again, it will still be using my old path.